# Check if token exist

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

How can i check if the token i'm sending to django exist? does jango rest framework has a built-in function to check this?

Currently i've the login and i'm creating the token each time a user logs in

```
c86177ae21c1c0b83a5c0354e742334ef2f376f3
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes - Django has an in-built method for this to detect whether querysets are not empty. Use the `.exists()` method, described in the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/

```py
if Authtoken.objects.filter(pk="c86177ae21c1c0b83a5c0354e742334ef2f376f3").exists():
        # returns True if the queryset is NOT empty.
```

Hope this helps ;)